# How to close ionic popover when not hover it in Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

How can I auto close ionic popover when not hover the button? you can test the hover button here >>>
[Test here updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3opnlh?file=src/components/Example.vue)

```
<ion-button id="hover-trigger">Hover Over Me</ion-button>
  <ion-popover trigger="hover-trigger" trigger-action="hover">
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">Hello World!</ion-content>
  </ion-popover>
```

Comment: hey meow, the link to your example is not working correctly.

Comment: @CitrusPunk hi I updated the link already

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that popover, like the name suggests, does pop over the whole website. So even if you would use Vues `@mouseout`-event to close the popover it would close immediately. Therefore there is no satisfying solution to this with `<ion-popover>` without restyling the whole component.



Alternatively Ionics `toastController` could be used to achieve a similar result but with the expected hover effect. We can use `@mouseover` and `@mouseout` to handle the hover events.
`@mouseover`: create an toast and present it.
`@mouseout`: dismiss the presented toast.
Here is an [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3opnlh-nss4yq?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FExample.vue)